# Is there a way to store more website information in WinSCP?

Tags: ftp, filezilla, winscp

**FileZilla Windows FTP Client**

Below is a screenshot from FileZilla, you will notice one of it;s best features is that it allows you to store anything in the notes section.  I often use this notes section to store things like WordPress login, phpMyAdmin login, or other related logins, domain names if different from Host, etc....

[image]

---

**WinSCP Windows Client**

This is all great except for the fact that I prefer to use WinSCP as it;s a bit more powerful and allows for more than just FTP login.  MY problem with storing my clients sites and my own in WinSCP is the lack of a comments/notes section.

Below is my screenshot from WinSCP that shows the lack of an area to store anymoire information for a record.  So my question is, for a Windows user, do you have a recommendation for a better FTP/SSH type client that stores website logins but alos has a place to store more information like FileZilla does?  Or even better, do you know of a plugin or anything to make WinSCP have this capability?

[image]

Comment: FileZilla doesn't just support FTP. It supports FTP, FTPS and SFTP. The only one missing is SCP.

Answer (score 3):

WinSCP supports this.

Use the [*Note page*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_note) on the Advanced Site Settings dialog:

[image: Note page]